# Move div with click and drag

Tags: javascript, html

I have a div on a website, that I’m currently working on and I would like to be able to move it around on the page with click and drag.

I found a cool script online, and I was able to change it to my needs, but it completely messes up the sizing of the div. – It seems, as if the div suddenly ignores all parents. I’m still kind of new to JS and can't seem to find what’s causing this problem.

I recreated the problem here: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Simon_R/6a9btkdn/101/) – I also added Notes in the HTML Part, that exactly explain the situation.

This is the script:

```
var mousePosition;
var offset = [0,0];
var object;
var isDown = false;

object = document.querySelector('#moveMe');

document.body.appendChild(object);

object.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
    isDown = true;
    offset = [
        object.offsetLeft - e.clientX,
        object.offsetTop - e.clientY
    ];
}, true);

document.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
    isDown = false;
}, true);

document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (isDown) {
        mousePosition = {

            x : event.clientX,
            y : event.clientY

        };
        object.style.left = (mousePosition.x + offset[0]) + 'px';
        object.style.top  = (mousePosition.y + offset[1]) + 'px';
    }
}, true);
```

Comment: It works for me correctly... 

Comment: @Zoldszemesostoros On my computer, when I replace the Placeholder with "moveMe" the size of the blue box changes, did you try that? 

Comment: btw, you have an error on your Fiddle `'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.`... you have `id="PLACEHOLDER"` instead of `id="moveMe"`.

Comment: @RioWeber I'm sorry, I'm not sure, if I understood, what you said correctly, but `PLACEHOLDER` is on purpose. That way you can see, how I want it to look. I said so in the the READ ME.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this line here:
`document.body.appendChild(object);`

It's taking the `#myDiv` div and moving it to the `<body>` so it no longer has the `#wrapper` div as a parent to set width against.

**Try just removing that line and it will work.**

Now if you're tyring to do something more complex where you need `#myDiv` to be moved to the body so that it's above all other elements you'll have to add a bit more JS.

Comment: Hey, this worked, thank you so much! :) – But I know have another problem: On my website, there is a div inside of `#myDiv` and that on does not move with the parent. Can I change the script, so that children, or that specific div move with the parent?

Comment: I'd have to see what it looks like: it works here just fine https://jsfiddle.net/b37m48g1/1/

Comment: I tried recreating the problem in JSFiddle and it does actually work: [Fiddle] (https://jsfiddle.net/Simon_R/6a9btkdn/106/) – So there has to be something else on my page, that causes this issue… This probably won't be before tomorrow, but I will try and find the cause and then post an update here, but again: Thank you!